# Is there any way to configure Visual Studio's Intellisense to pick the instance variable instead of the class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

Every time I use a variable name that's the same as a class name, Visual Studio's Intellisense always selects the class name by default:

[image]

This is quite annoying. I'd like it to, by default, always pick the instance variable instead of the class. Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2010 to do this? I'm also using Resharper 5.1 if that helps.

Comment: That naming convention is not that good if you're doing Player.Player. Might want to consider another naming schema :P And having instance members with the same name as the class sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Jes: The property is in a different class.  This is a common pattern.

Comment: SLaks is right, my `Player` property is in another class.

Comment: Oh ok I thought you meant that the variable was the same as the class name that held it.

Comment: First of all, this is ReSharper's own completion (as opposed to the default VS completion.) Also, there's no instance variable in the suggestion list in your screenshot. Are you sure it's available in this particular position at all?

Comment: @goro: The 2nd one is a property, which is an instance variable.

Comment: ReSharper still does this, the auto-completion to fully qualified class instead of instance variable with same name thing. It's very annoying. For those wondering (why?) It's for POCOs to be easily serializable with both XML and JSON with minimum attributes when said XML and JSON are always lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Selecting either one will result in the same text, so you can just always select the class.

Comment: If I press period after the Intellisense comes up, I'll get `TestGame.Player` instead of just `Player`. I have to hit escape in order to clear the Intellisense pop-up before I can press period.

Comment: Oh.  That's a Resharper feature.  I don't use Resharper, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks anyway SLaks. I'll try digging through Resharper's features to see if I can disable that autocomplete behavior.